# UITableView doesn't scroll automatically if the datasource changes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UITableView` with two arrays as datasource. I also have one `UISegmentedControl` to switch between these arrays. I use the `segmentedControlChanged` method to call the `reloadData` method.
This works fine.

But there is one problem.

For example arrayOne has 1 item and arrayTwo has 10 items.
So if I switch to the arrayTwo and scroll to the bottom of the tableview and after that switch back to arrayOne the tableview stays scrolled down and i don't see any item. But if I start scrolling, the tableview "jumps" automatically to the first item.

So my question is, how can i trigger this behaviour automatically when the tabledata source changes?

Comment: I think, You must reload tableView, when switch segment button.

Comment: @iDeveloper i call reloadData() in the segmentedControl changed.

Comment: can you please upload code snippet

Comment: Try this `tableView.scrollsToTop = true`

Comment: are you loading the new data on the main thread?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one of following two lines after reloading table

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true)
```

or

```
mainTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i don't know how you change data source of tableview but i use this method for my data source switches.

I create 3 arrays;

```
 var mainArr = [String]()
 var sortedArr = [String]()
 var arrToReturn : [String] {
    if segmentedController.selectedIndex == 0 {
        return mainArr
    }
    else {
        return sortedArr
    }
}
```

I always return `arrToReturn` for tableView data source.

When it comes to your scrolling issue, it sounds like you are reloading tableView before changing its dataSource.

After that when you start scrolling, tableView reloads cells and can't find old items and automatically sets its scrolling position to start of screen.

Also do you have any code about setting tableviews scrolling position even if it is irrelevant? If you have you should check it.